# Black background slide up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wrapper, slideup

It is probably very simple but i'm stuck trying to make a homepage automatic background slider like here : https://www.jackdavison.co.uk

That's probably Jquery but I found a way to have something similar with html and Css, only it keeps repeating.

Any help ?

You can see my code here:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliding-background {
  background-color: black; 
  height: 560px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 4000ms;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0px, -2000px, 0px);

  }

}
```

[See on Codepen here](https://codepen.io/Chacam/pen/vYOXWMW)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a minor change in your CSS. Just change `animation: slide 2s linear infinite;` to `animation: slide 0.6s ease-out forwards;`. Also, I have changed in `-2000px` to `100%` in `@keyframes` in case if you have a full-height background.

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` Let your element retain the style values from the last keyframe when the animation ends.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliding-background {
  background-color: black; 
  height: 560px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slide 0.6s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 2000ms;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the animation and keep the last state use:

```
.sliding-background {         
     animation: slide 2s linear;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help the clean code is this one :

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliding-background {
  background-color: black; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: slide 0.6s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 2000ms;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px); 
  }
}
```